# How do I find gaps between array values in MASM?

Tags: loops, sum, masm

If array is {0, 2, 5, 9, 10} as doublewords and has gaps of 2, 3, 4 and 1, whose sum equals 10, I don't know how to find gaps and adding those. Please need help.

```
.data
array DWORD 0, 2, 5, 9, 10
.code
main PROC
mov
```

Comment: Sounds like you want something like `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) sum += array[n+1] - array[n];`. That should be pretty easy to translate into assembly.